# Why shouldn't I use shared_ptr and unique_ptr always and instead use normal pointers?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have a background in *C#* and *obj-c* so RC/GC are things I (still) hold dear to me. As I started learning *C++* in more depth, I can't stop wondering why I would use normal pointers when they are so *unmanaged* instead of other alternative solutions?

the *shared_ptr* provides a great way to store references and not lose track of them without deleting them. I can see practical approaches for *normal* pointers but they seem just bad practices.

Can someone make of case of these alternatives?

Comment: You can't use `shared_ptr` everywhere without thinking (in contrast, you can use GC-managed references for everything), because then you'll be dumbfounded when you inevitable create cyclic references. When you program C++, you **have** to think about ownership. There's just no way around it. That is not to say you shouldn't use them (you should), but choosing the right one isn't a no brainer.

Comment: Plus, copying a `shared_ptr` as well as having it go out of scope has noticeable overhead since it requires atomic operations in the best case, locks in the worst case (the standard guarantees that this is thread-safe). Copying a raw pointer is almost a no-op.

Comment: @Damon Actually, in C++, you probably have to think less about ownership than in C#, because you should be using value semantics (and you don't have to think about who owns an object on the stack).  Where as I've had problems in Java because the ownership (in the largest sense of the word) wasn't clear.  (Who "owns" the `java.awt.Dimension` returned by `java.awt.Component.getSize()`, for example?)

Comment: So _unmanaged_ pointers, yeah, time flies quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone else mentioned, in C++ you have to consider ownership.  That being said, the 3D networked multiplayer FPS I'm currently working on has an official rule called "No new or delete."  It uses only shared and unique pointers for designating ownership, and raw pointers retrieved from them (using `.get()`) everywhere that we need to interact with C API's.  The performance hit is not noticeable.  I use this as an example to illustrate the negligible performance hit since games/simulations typically have the strictest performance requirements.

This has also significantly reduced the amount of time spent debugging and hunting down memory leaks.  In theory, a well-designed application would never run into these problems.  In real life working with deadlines, legacy systems, or existing game engines that were poorly designed, however, they are an inevitability on large projects like games... unless you use smart pointers.  If you must dynamically allocate, don't have ample time for designing/rewriting the architecture or debugging problems related to resource management, and you want to get it off the ground as quickly as possible, smart pointers are the way to go and incur no noticeable performance cost even in large-scale games.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation?  If it is because copying objects would be too expensive (a very possible case in games software), then smart pointers (probably some sort of invasive smart pointer, rather than `std::shared_ptr`) might be indicated.  But in a lot of cases, this shouldn't be the case.  A smart pointer won't handle entity objects correctly, for example: when a `Weapon` gets a `hitByDisintegratorBlast` event, for example, it might end up doing `delete this`, which will _not_ work with smart pointers.

Comment: Yeah that does seem pretty arbitrary :).

Comment: I'm curious as to how you think you would not have dynamically allocated objects in a game?  Textures, shaders, meshes, animations, sounds, music, etc., all are rather large and their ownership is shared by multiple other resources.

Comment: @uberwulu great response, i'm curious what game engine are you using?

Answer (score 11):

Ofcourse you're encouraged to use shared and unique ptr IF they're owning pointers. If you only need an observer however, a raw pointer will do just fine (a pointer bearing no responsibility for whatever it points to).

There is basically no overhead for `std::uniqe_ptr` and there is some in `std::shared_ptr` as it does reference counting for you, but rarely will you ever need to save on execution time here.

Also, there is no need for "smart" pointers if you can guarantee lifetime / ownership hierarchy by design; say a parent node in a tree outliving its children - although this is slightly related to the fact whether the pointer actually owns something.

Answer (score 6):

The question is more the opposite: why should you use smart
pointers?  Unlike C# (and I think Obj-C), C++ makes extensive
use of value semantics, which means that unless an object has an
application specific lifetime (in which case, none of the smart
pointers apply), you will normally be using value semantics, and
no dynamic allocation.  There are exceptions, but if you make it
a point of thinking in terms of value semantics (e.g. like
`int`), of defining appropriate copy constructors and assignment
operators where necessary, and *not* allocating dynamically
unless the object has an externally defined lifetime, you'll
find that you rarely need to do anything more; everything just
takes care of itself.  Using smart pointers is very much the
exception in most well written C++.

Comment: Your answer is not only incorrect but would be misleading to new developers. You will regularly need to use dynamic objects where your N comes from config files or when dealing with containers. In most complex applications like games you will probably have objects floating around and being member of multiple containers at a time. You simply can't use by-value semantics with this. Look at large code base like Unreal Engine (very well written code, IMO)  and you will see tons of dynamically allocated objects all over all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to interoperate with C APIs, in which case you'll need to use raw pointers
for at least those parts of the code.

Comment: Oh, nice, this actually slipped my answer! :) But I wrap these in pretty pretty C++ and don't look back!

Answer (score 1):

In embedded systems, pointers are often used to access registers of hardware chips or memory at specific addresses.

Since the hardware registers already exist, there is no need to dynamically allocate them.  There won't be any memory leaks if the pointer is deleted or its value changed.

Similarly with function pointers.  Functions are not dynamically allocated and they have "fixed" addresses.  Reassigning a function pointer or deleting one will not cause a memory leak.